# How to start a number of moving Sprite objects on different time?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, andengine

I created a live wallpaper service using AndEngine library. On screen there are a number of bird Sprite objects that flying repeatedly from the left to right started in random y-coordinate (I'm using LoopEntityModifier and PathModifier for this, see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244310/how-to-set-pathmodifiers-coordinates-randomly-in-start-of-loopentitymodifier) if you're curious). The birds shouldn't start flying in same time, but there is a gap/interval about 3 seconds before another bird showed up from left most screen.

The question is what technique that I have to use to achieve that?

I had created array of Sprites to hold the bird sprites. The code is like this...

```
public class MyLiveWallpaperService extends BaseLiveWallpaperService {

    private BirdSprite[] birdSprites;    // BirdSprite is actually an extension class from AnimatedSprite
    ...

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        ...
        birdSprites= new BirdSprite[4];
        for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
            birdSprites[i] = new BirdSprite(0, 0, birdTextureRegion);

            scene.getChild(LAYER_FRONT).attachChild(birdSprites[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code produces four birds that show-up on left screen in same time. I tried by adding Thread.sleep(3000) before calling attachChild, but it affects whole application. The live wallpapaper application become hanged for several seconds when started.

Comment: Show the code to move the birds please

Comment: [DelayModifier](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/modifier/DelayModifier.java?r=6b3472ea81986361b356e6dfd023a8ceddbb05a4)?

Comment: @Snicolas: to move the bird I use PathModifier, you can see the code at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244310/how-to-set-pathmodifiers-coordinates-randomly-in-start-of-loopentitymodifier

Comment: @Stefan Hanke: I tried putting DelayModifier at the Sprite's constructor, the code is like this: registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(new DelayModifier(10), new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(10, path), 1, this)));. But they're still showing up together. I believe the code that start the sprite's modifier is: scene.getChild(LAYER_FRONT).attachChild(birdSprites[i]);. So I guess something must be done at onLoadScene, right?

Comment: Sorry; bad council. This does not solve your original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found by using TimerHandler:

```
    scene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(3, true, new ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            // your code here will be executed every 3 seconds (see 1st argument of TimerHandler)
            ...
            scene.getChild(LAYER_FRONT).attachChild(birdSprites[i]);
        }
    }));
```

Please let me know if you have better solution.